# Significant delay while deleting .exe file in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7

Issue: If I try to delete a folder that contains an executable(s), all the files except the EXEs get deleted. Using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) also doesn't show any processes holding a lock on these files. The EXEs get deleted after several minutes or a reboot. Searching for a solution led me to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/234569/windows-7-delayed-file-delete) and the solution for re-enabling PCA and AE services works.

The strange part is that this issue NEVER occurs on a Win7 x32 at my office. It only occurs on an x64 version. Is there any specific reason for it to occur only on x64 and also how does enabling the above mentioned services help fix the problem?

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using a custom Windows install (built using RT7Lite), and I removed both of the services you mention completely from my operating system - and I experience no such side-effects (all of my files delete immediately).  Do you hold *the* Administrator account on the machine, or another account (admin or not)?

Comment: Check this topic, can be useful
I was with the same problem, and activate the service "Application Experience" fixed the problem. http://superuser.com/questions/234569/windows-7-delayed-file-delete

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some antivisrus/antimalware/antispyware/firewall on your x64 PC?

Even if you have no 3rd-party security solution installed keep in mind that there is Microsoft Defender, Microsoft Antimalware and Microsoft Security Essentials.
The last one check all the files you interact with, I had a lot of problems with it: explorer and [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) hangs and lags (during copy, paste, commit, update operations).

So my suggestion is to try to disable all the security solutions (installed and built-in) and try to repeat .exe removal operations.