# Can't delete "unlocked" EXE files in Windows with administrator rights

Tags: windows-7, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 delayed file delete](https://superuser.com/questions/234569/windows-7-delayed-file-delete)

Lately I have this problem regarding deleting EXE files on my Windows 7 installation.

**Facts:**

- I am an administrator on this computer.
- The file is not locked by any process. (checked with Unlocker)
- The program (exe file) is not running in the background.
- There aren't any file system inconsistencies. (checked with CHKDSK)
- There are no bad sectors on my hard drive.

**Problem:** Whenever I try to delete an exe file, the deleting process completes successfully, but the file won't disappear from Windows Explorer (tried also the cmd, the file is still there). Whenever I do a software upgrade (which needs to replace an exe file) it finishes with an error: *"Can't replace file xyz.exe"*.

The idea is that the file will disappear after 1-2 minutes after being deleted.

I'm a developer and I can tell that building a source code drives me mad, because the exe file can't be replaced by the compiler, only after I manually delete the file and wait for 1-2 minutes for it to disappear.

**What I have already tried:**

- Scanning the computer for malware/viruses and all kinds of threats.
- Deactivating/uninstalling the antivirus protection.
- Checking the hardware for any problems (mainly my hard disk drive).
- Deleting from safe mode works (but I don't want to restart my computer every time I need to delete an exe file).

Comment: Have you tried external file Explorers apart from Explorer

Comment: Tried another external file explorer, not working.

Tried the solution offered by _Guganeshan.T_ and it seems to work for the moment. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can answer your own problems and select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to save someone the time of traversing several links and then reading lots of irrelevant information, based on the link in the update I just did the following:

1. launch services.msc
2. Scroll down to Application Experience
3. Double - click
4. In resulting dialog set Startup type: popup to Automatic.
5. Click OK

Note, I did NOT turn on Program Compatibility Assistant and so far it appears to have solved the problem.